# How I can find out about rock concerts in Tallinn?

Tags: online-resources, music, tallinn

How I can find a program for rock concerts in Tallinn?

I am ideally looking for a website where such concerts are listed.

Comment: "All possible events" sounds like a very tall order.

Comment: all possible events in rock and metal. It is defined actually above. I mean, it should be a website, where I can find the possible events in Helsinki for the year 2016

Comment: x @Guforu: I doubt either Finland or Estonia has laws that require rock/metal concerts to be submitted to a particular website up to a year in advance! Sometimes such things happen on short notice.

Comment: With a very quick reseach I found these about Helsinki

http://www.songkick.com/metro_areas/28825-finland-helsinki
and
http://eventful.com/helsinki/events/categories/music_metal

Comment: `Haloo Helsinki` They are a popular band in Finland, follow them

Comment: A google search for "[city name] events" or "[city name] concerts" usually turns up websites that have calendars of various local events.

Comment: I think this is too broad. Not only because there will be a ton of concerts that are probably not organised in a central place but also because the cities have little in common other than being on opposite sides of a stretch of sea.

Comment: For me this question falls under 'goods and services', sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Tallinn:** Although I don't attend many concerts most of the tickets are usually being sold on [piletilevi.ee](http://piletilevi.ee).